# recovery and join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

For a back-end web project, we use PHP 7.4 and MySQL 8.X, here is the structure of a part of the DB

```
CREATE TABLE `availability ` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
  `student_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_2CBACE2FDDEAB1A3` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2CBACE2FDDEAB1A3` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sex_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `picture` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `cv` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_717E22E3448F3B3C` (`sex_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_717E22E3448F3B3C` FOREIGN KEY (`sex_id`) REFERENCES `sex` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

```
CREATE TABLE `request` (
  `id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `student_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `content` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_2694D7A5DDEAB1A3` (`student_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_2694D7A5DDEAB1A3` FOREIGN KEY (`student_id`) REFERENCES `student` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Here are the cardinalities:

- a STUDENT can have several availabilities (no matter what the
  category of the availability is) an AVAILABILITY can belong to one or
  more STUDENTS
- a student can have one or more APPLICATIONS
- a REQUEST belongs to only one STUDENT

but when I try to retrieve all the REQUESTS according to a period, it retrieves the data twice:

```
SELECT DE.*, ET.picture AS picture_editor, CONCAT(ET.first_name, ' ', ET.name) AS name_editeur, DI.start, DI.end
FROM request DE
INNER JOIN student ET ON ET.id = DE.student_id
INNER JOIN availability DI ON DI.student_id = DE.student_id
WHERE DI.start< CAST('2022-12-31' AS DATETIME) AND DI.end> CAST('2022-09-11' AS DATETIME)
```

Can you help me as I want to retrieve the data according to the student's availability

Comment: it retrieves the data twice... Using "group by" could be a solution no...?

Comment: what do you mean retrieves the data twice? can you provide desired and actual output?

Comment: Sorry I don't know of a website where I can put my DB online for you to test.

If you know of any, please let me know.

Comment: There are quite a few available, and they can be found by simple searching. https://dbfiddle.uk/ is one of them. Also you must change your question title to English please. And yes, sample data and expected output would help us a lot. Your question has made a good start but a little more is needed.

Comment: Here's a fiddle based on what you've posted so far: https://dbfiddle.uk/2uDxALD7 . As you can see, it needs a little bit of work. You can update it and provide the new link to us.

Comment: Is PHP related to the question? If so please add the code, if not please remove the tag.. dual returns could be not specifying fetch mode.

Comment: Without sharing sample data and the expected output, it's difficult to see where this is going wrong

Comment: here is the link to test my DB: https://dbfiddle.uk/oi7sg0tf

Comment: Did you see the problem?

Comment: @JosueElonga can you replicate the problem (duplicate result) on that fiddle? i do have an inkling that the problem is not on the mysql but on the data being stored in your database - given a single `student_id` can technically has two or more overlapping availabilities.

Comment: @Bagus Tesa you can see the result with duplicates when a student has two availabilities and also two applications

Comment: @JosueElonga does the term "application" refers to "request" on the DDL above?

Comment: sorry, let me clarify what you want to achieve. you wanted to **get the date range within `availability` for a given `student` and then find all `request` within the timeframe**, am i right? a sample data and expected output will be really helpful in conveying what you want to achieve.